# Google maps multiple holes in a polygon

Tags: google-maps, polygon, polygons

I am doing a polygon with holes in google maps but I have a problem, often holes intersect with this result:
http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/5414/fyp8.png

I don't wanna that, 
there's any form to  join the holes?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to merge the intersecting polygons into a single hole.

Comment: I see ... in google maps android API there is the property holes, why not in normal web version... :S